# Optimize over a General Product

Tags: r

So I wrote this cute function to generalize MLE problems solutions to MLE problems.

```
# Π f(x | θs) for x ∈ xs
# 
# Useful for things like multiplying iid likelihoods/pdfs
# 
# fn - the PDF/likelihood/whatever function
# xs - known values
# thetas - the space to explore
`Πf(x|θs)` = function(fn, xs, thetas) {
  # Matrix with columns as fn(x, θ) for each x in xs
  xs_given_θs = sapply(xs, function(x) fn(x, thetas))
  # Take sum of each row to find joint function
  apply(xs_given_θs, 1, prod)
}
```

In theory, I was expecting to be able to do something fancy like this:

```
require(purrr)
likelihood = partial(`Πf(x|θs)`,
  fn = function(k, θ) θ^k * exp(-θ) / factorial(k),
  xs = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)

# This above is a partial application of arguments.
#
# likelihood(thetas) will now compute the likelihood for thetas
# given the above xs and supplied function.

optimize(likelihood, c(0, 10), maximum = T)
```

but this chokes during the optimization routine during the `apply` step:

```
 Error in apply(sapply(xs, function(x) fn(x, thetas)), 1, prod) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Can someone explain what the optimization routine is doing which is causing the failure, and how I can rewrite `Πf(x|θs)` to prevent this from happening?

---

Note the same issue arises even if I'm dealing with log-likelihoods:

```
# Σ loglikelihood(x | θs) for x ∈ xs
# 
# Useful for things like summing iid log likelihoods/pdfs
# 
# fn - the log(PDF/likelihood/whatever) function
# xs - known values
# thetas - the space to explore
`Σloglik(x|θs)` = function(fn, xs, thetas) {
  # Matrix with columns as fn(x, θ) for each x in xs
  xs_given_θs = sapply(xs, function(x) fn(x, thetas))
  # Take product of each row to find joint function
  apply(xs_given_θs, 1, sum)
}
```

Comment: Where does the `partial` function come from? And generally, the first argument of the function passed to optimize is `x`, rather than a function

Comment: Also I don't see any arguments being passed to `thetas`.

Comment: In general you will have much better numerical results dealing with *log*-likelihoods.

Comment: That's fine, but the same issue would arise if I tried to generalize a `Σloglik(x | θs)` function.